# can i use fgets for accepting strings in character pointer array instead of scanf

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, fgets

Although the below code is working fine.But its showing "segmentation fault" when i am trying to accept the strings using fgets as i want to store strings which might contain spaces.How to accept strings (which might contain spaces) 
in character pointer array

```
int main(){
    char* nm[5];
    char* st;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        //fgets(nm[i],30,stdin);
        scanf("%ms",&nm[i]);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%s\n",nm[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**nm** is a pointer to 5 chars not a pointer to 5 strings, so **&nm[2]** is the address of the 3rd char in nm.  If you change nm to be

```
char* nm[5][50];
```

you will have an array of 5 x 50 chars.  That should stop the segfault.

Comment: Neil please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/50667860/10212490.I think nm[2] points to the base address of 3rd string in the array

Comment: `nm` is not a pointer to 5 `char`s, but an _array_ of 5 pointers to `char`.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Even the analysis it gives is wrong.

Comment: BTW, "*a pointer to 5 chars*" would be defined as `char (*pointer_to_array_of_5_char)[5];`

Comment: I knew my c was rusty but I didn't think it was that bad 